# Microsoft Teams JS - Auth Url is not valid

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

We have recently tried to update our teams app to use the microsoft teams js authentication so that we could external sign ins in a new window. The function being authentication.authenticate()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab (As an example, we are actually a message extension)

This works great on the browser and local testing for both the teams desktop app and the browser as well. I was able to successfully get the authentication window to popup for both when adding the proper values for the manifest file.

However we seem to have an issue once the application is deployed to the store that the auth url is not valid. This has made it so that the popup will never display on the desktop app once deployed. Local testing with an ngrok server works correctly locally (As recommend by the various posts we have been working with)  When displaying the error from the authentication.authenticate code, we receive the error "Auth url is not valid"

We believe we have put into place all the valid domains however it may be an issue with the way we deploy our app. Currently we just push an update to bitbucket and it is automatically deployed through the deployment center portion of our app service. When checking the console, it is showing our klyckio.azurewebsites.net address as a url in the manifest, so perhaps there's another url we are missing for the deployment.

I've hidden our realm and clientid for the purpose of keeping this secure for any clients, but they are normally set here.

The manifest file includes the following entries

```
"klyckio.azurewebsites.net",
"app.klyck.io",
"c2c3-208-96-94-145.ngrok-free.app",
"*.botframework.com",
"waws-prod-blu-171.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net",
"klyckio.scm.azurewebsites.net"
```

They are some in this list that were attempts to find out why it is still being blocked and if we are perhaps missing a url that we needed to have included

Here is the auth url we are calling [https://app.klyck.io/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id={{ClientId}}d&redirect_uri=https://klyckio.azurewebsites.net/klyckIoMessageExtension/token.html](https://app.klyck.io/auth/realms/%7B%7Brealm%7D%7D/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%7B%7BClientId%7D%7Dd&redirect_uri=https://klyckio.azurewebsites.net/klyckIoMessageExtension/token.html)